# for comprehension to yield map

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I try to use for comprehension to make a map of string to MyData case class.

Here is what I tried unsuccessfully :

```
case class MyDataProperty(name: String, value: String)
case class MyData(props: List[MyDataProperty])


def makeMyData(configs: List[Config]): Map[String, MyData] = {
    for {
      // loop through all configurations
      conf <- configs
      // Retrieve each config's list of properties and make a list of MyDataProperty object from it
      props <- for(prop <- conf.properties) yield (MyDataProperty(prop.name, prop.value))
    } yield (conf.name -> MyData(props)) toMap
}
```

This code gives me multiple compile errors.  What is the correct way to build this kind of nest for comprehension and yield a map ?

Comment: What are the compile errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for comprehensions` your code should look like following:

```
def makeMyData(configs: List[Config]): Map[String, MyData] =
  (for {
    conf <- configs
    props = for (prop <- conf.properties) yield MyDataProperty(prop.name, prop.value)
  } yield conf.name -> MyData(props)).toMap
```